# Detecting candidates when Outline Level has children but no more Parents

Tags: excel, vba, formula, counting, levels

Fistly many apologies as my original thread I cudnt seem to respond with pictures to explain after some really sound advice!

Basically I have the following data in a spreadsheet:

[image]

In Column G I want to put a 1 in the cell when a parent has children BUT no other Parents. I want to do this for all records in the sheet.

To update column E so I know which is a Parent and a Child I use the following function:

[image]

This helps me identify the Rows but im stuck in how I can exclude those Parents which have children but also more Parents. Here is another example:

[image]

This example is correct as it has no more Parents but does have children.

In the last example you can see theirs more Parents but also a Child so this needs to be excluded. Can anybody help me how to resolve excluding Parents which have more Parents?

Thankyou

[image]